# is angularjs working with database or json?

Tags: json, angularjs, database, angularjs-scope

I am developing web application. I am getting data in json or database. I can use this data in angularjs at one time (i think so). So if any data changed in json or database then angularjs should work .Is this how it normally works? Is it possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question here

Comment: As you know angularjs work on real time, when user submit form, that data will display in another page using angularjs. But I don't have submit form data. I have database or json data and this data change anytime. So How can I use angularjs in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. When we say data binding in Angular JS, we are referring the data in memory and manipulations we do to the data. For instance when we type in text field, we update a javascript object, and then display it in another form on the browser.

When dealing with external data, e.g. json or database, we will need to fetch that data from the server. Browser on the client side won't know that json has been changed in the server, it needs to send a request to the server to fetch new data. After the data is loaded into memory, then we can do the same manipulation and display it.

The remaining question is when to trigger the data refresh. Well this is not an easy question for web application if you are using restful API. It can be reactive like when user do specific action, or refresh at fixed interval, depends on your requirement. I heard that socket programming is good for this kind of thing but I'm not expert in it so I'll leave it to others.

Answer (score 1):

Angular apps usually manage their data using RESTful API endpoints. This means, that your Angular app communicates (usually via JSON) with a backend application running on a server, which handles all database interaction.

In practice this means that to get for example all blog articles, in your Angular app you would do a `$http` GET request to `api.yoursite.com/articles`. Then your backend application does database query and returns a JSON with all the articles.

Does this answer your question? Because it wasn't clear what exactly you were asking.